# How to convert AudioFrame[AudioGraph] PCM buffer to AAC in Windows UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, audio, uwp, aac

How to convert [AudioFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.AudioFrame) PCM buffer to AAC in UWP? I am capturing Microphone data in AudioFrames using [AudioFrameOutputNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Audio.AudioFrameOutputNode) of [AudioGraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs).

```
    AudioFrameOutputNode frameOutputNode;

    private void CreateFrameOutputNode()
    {
        frameOutputNode = audioGraph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
        audioGraph.QuantumStarted += AudioGraph_QuantumStarted;
    }

    private void AudioGraph_QuantumStarted(AudioGraph sender, object args)
    {
        AudioFrame frame = frameOutputNode.GetFrame();
        ProcessFrameOutput(frame);

    }

    /* AudioFrame buffer will be in PCM format */
    unsafe private void ProcessFrameOutput(AudioFrame frame)
    {
        using (AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Write))
        using (IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference())
        {
            byte* dataInBytes;
            uint capacityInBytes;
            float* dataInFloat;

            // Get the buffer from the AudioFrame
            ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacityInBytes);

            dataInFloat = (float*)dataInBytes;

            //TO DO
            //Convert PCM data to AAC data
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at Media Foundation transforms.  This is a native framework (the successor of DirectShow), but there are some managed libraries out there that have done all the necessary Interop declarations to make them easily callable from managed code. In particular look for the `AACEncoder`transform.

Comment: [AACEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742785?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) transform requirement says minimum supported client - Windows 7 [desktop apps only]. Will it work on WIndows Mobile?

Comment: Missed the uwp tag in your question, sorry, I guess then it is not an option.